# RBAC what is the recommended method for Role->Task->Operation

Tags: php, yii, rbac

I started using srbac in Yii.

The options that are available: create a role, task and operation and then assign:
Operation to Task, Task to Role.

My question is: 
do i need to create a task for each operation? 
because i want to assign 1 operation to the lowest user level, and 4 operations to the super admin.

hope i was clear,
Danny

Comment: possible duplicate of: [How to make a program do what I want not what a program does?](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

Comment: I don't think so. Is not so easy to get involved in the RBAC scheme thata Yii offers :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Role*, *Task* and *Operation* are all '**authorization items**', you've to had it present. They only provide a way to organize permissions in a **tree** way, and then you can choose whatever node of the tree and assign it to a user. Of course it is also possible to assign multiple nodes to a user, being leafs or not.

If you only need to design a very **simple** app, you can simply create 4 'operations' (or tasks, or roles), and assign them under your criteria to the users. But **tree scheme** is recommended for medium-big apps.

Comment: Yeap...that's what i thought, except my app is complected so i guess i have to do it manually 
I really need 4 tasks and each of those 4 has 4 operations (view,delete,new,edit) and some of my users are not allowed to edit for example...so in theory i had to create a task for each...this is quite limiting

Comment: One solution would be to create extra tasks to group users: a task with only view permissions, a task with all permissions except edit...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar question, I think, some time ago when I dived into RBAC in Yii. I think that what's need to be cleared out is **what's the real meaning of an operation, task and role**. My conclusions are laid out [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/28993-what-exactly-are-tasks-in-yiis-rbac/page__view__findpost__p__139568) and are based on a nice comment from the Yii project founder himself, found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/2313-rbac-confusion/page__p__16035#entry16035). In a nutshell, operations are the most basic building blocks (a-la atoms of the Yii RBAC world). Developers (**and they only**) define those and build tasks from them. A task is composed from one or more operations. A role is built from tasks (at least one).

In my design, I use tasks as the basic building blocks and examples to tasks is "edit own profile", "create article", "send private message", etc... . To me, breaking those auth items to finer granularity is an [over-design](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overdesign).

Also, I think that your app's RBAC tree shouldn't fit the simple requirements its facing now but rather be more robust from the start. I recommend setting up tasks and roles and assign roles to users. I find this a more intuitive way to maintain the site.